# Car not starting sometimes without pressing acceleration

Tags: engine, starting

I have swift vxi 2014 with odometer 1.5Lakh Kilo meters and its 5 Years old. Some time my car is not starting without accelerator. After starting car runs fine with no issue.
The only thing is the clutch work is pending on my car. But I don't think this clutch work is related to the starting problem. 
Please help me about this issue.

Comment: Some cars like starting with a bit of accelerator pedal and others don’t... Do what works for your car.

Comment: Is this something that started recently, or has it always been this way?

Comment: @GdD .... no no not always .. its just started a few days back.